# Share connection details with container and host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml` contains application container and database container

```
app:
  links:
   - db

db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - 5003:5432
```

Let's say that during development I want to start only `db` container and to connect to it and I use `localhost:5003`.

In production I want to start both containers, one with application and one with database. But now I need to use `db:5432` in application container to connect to `db`

Is it possible to modify docker-compose configuration file to be able to use same database uri in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create multiple docker-compose files for the different environments.

You can create a base docker-compose file and add overrides for the different environments as described here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#different-environments

Comment: I have already two of them. But it does not answer the question. Problem is that you need to use different database uri from different "environments"